# How to get the name of an item for an event (minecraft plugin)

Tags: java, events, event-handling

I've managed to code everything and debug everything on my own which is an accomplishment, well everything except one thing..

I need help figuring out how to check the name of an item and if the item has that specific name, THEN the event will happen. I'm trying to check if a chicken egg has a specific mob name, like creeper, or spider, and if so, that mob will spawn out of the egg. (I know they have mob eggs for that but I'm messing around with my abilities atm.)

**Here's the code for the command:**

```
public class EggCommands implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("egg") && sender instanceof Player) {
            if (args.length == 0) {
                player.sendMessage("Usage: /egg <mob>");
                return true;
            }
            if (args[0].equals("creeper")) {
                if (player.getInventory().getSize() == -1) {
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You're inventory is full");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.EGG, 1);
                    ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
                    meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "Creeper");
                    ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>();
                    lore.add(ChatColor.RED + "Spawns A Charged Creeper With Lightning Effect");
                    meta.setLore(lore);
                    item.setItemMeta(meta);
                    player.getInventory().addItem(item);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Here's the code for the Event Listener:**

```
public class EggListener implements Listener {

public EggListener(EggMain plugin) {
    plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
        }

        @EventHandler
        public void Eggs(PlayerEggThrowEvent e) {
            if (e.getEgg().getCustomName().equals(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "Creeper")) {
                    e.setHatchingType(EntityType.CREEPER);
                    e.setNumHatches((byte) 1);
                    e.setHatching(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason why your code won't work is that you're comparing two different names. You set the name of an ItemStack to "Creeper", but then in the `PlayerEggThrowEvent` you check if the Egg's name is the same as the ItemStack, it is not.
An egg is an entity, its name is the same as a nametag over a zombie's or a player's head, not the same as an ItemStack. The egg will infact have no name unless you set one.

I experimented a while and came up with this structure, it's not working but might give you a head start:

```
private HashMap<UUID, ItemStack> eggThrown = new HashMap<UUID, ItemStack>();

@EventHandler
public void eggthrown(PlayerEggThrowEvent event) {
    if(eggThrown.containsKey(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId())) {
        ItemStack egg = eggThrown.get(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
    }
}

@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
public void storeEgg(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) || event.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
        if(event.hasItem() && event.getItem().getType().equals(Material.EGG)) {
            eggThrown.put(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId(), event.getItem());
        }
    }
}
```

What I do is use PlayerInteractEvent to retrieve the egg's ItemStack, this event is called only when a player right clicks (throws an egg) thanks to the if statements. I then put the ItemStack into a hashmap we can use in the PlayerEggThrowEvent. When we have the ItemStack we can compare the names.

Another solution would be cancel whatever event that gets called when the egg is spawned into the world and give it a custom name.